# Mongoose save() not saving changes

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have a fully functioning CRUD app that I'm building some additional functionality for. The new functionality allows users to make changes to a list of vendors. They can add new vendors, update them and delete them. The add and delete seem to be working just fine, but updating doesn't seem to be working even though it follows a similar method I use in the existing CRUD functionality elsewhere in the app. Here's my code:

```
// async function from AXIOS request
const { original, updatedVendor } = req.body;
let list = await Vendor.findOne({ id: 1 });

if (!list) return res.status(500).json({ msg: 'Vendors not found' });

let indexOfUpdate = list.vendors.findIndex(
  (element) => element.id === original.id
);

list.vendors[indexOfUpdate].id = updatedVendor.id;
list.vendors[indexOfUpdate].name = updatedVendor.name;

const updated = await list.save();
res.json(updated);
```

The `save()` isn't updating the existing document on the DB side. I've console logged that the `list.vendors` array of objects is, indeed, being changed, but `save()` isn't doing the saving.

EDIT:
A note on the manner of using save, this format doesn't work either:

```
list.save().then(res.json(list));
```

EDIT 2:
To answer the questions about seeing the logs, I cannot post the full console.log(list.vendors) as it contains private information, however, I can confirm that the change made to the list *is showing up* when I run the following in the VendorSchema:

```
VendorSchema.post('save', function () {
  console.log(util.inspect(this, { maxArrayLength: null }));
});
```

However, the save still isn't changing the DB side.

Comment: .delete the `const updated` .try returning `list`

Comment: @AnkushVerma I did. This was a new attempt at resolving the issue based on the Mongoose documentation for ``save()``. Before it was simply ``list.save().then(res.json(list))`` which also didn't save.

Comment: is there any error that you might be able to provide?

Comment: try adding this code to your model. `SchemaName.post('save',function(){ console.log(this)})`

Comment: 1- are you sure there is a vendor with id = 1 in db? .... 
2- if yes, console.log(list), and check if it has vendors array or not? .... 
3- console.log(indexOfUpdate) too ... 
could you add all of these logs to the question, and the Vendor Schema as well?

Comment: @MohammedYousry Posted EDIT 2 for this. To answer your points, 1, yes, I've designed the entry in the DB to be a single document containing an array of objects in the object format of ``{"id": String, "name": String}``. The array contains around 150 objects with unique ids and names.
2, There is a confirmed vendors array of objects.
3, The indexOfUpdate returns with the correct index value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you are using nested objects, Mongoose will not be able to detect the changes made. You need to mark the modified as an object before the `save`

```
list.markModified('vendors');
```